# Error: "Is iOS Build Agent available and logged in?" after rebooting Mac build host

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I get the error

```
Is iOS Build Agent available and logged in? No ipa output found using path: C:\dev\src\......\bin\iPhone\Debug\*.ipa
```

when trying to build my iOS app from Visual Studio after rebooting my mac build host.

What is the **minimum** I have to do to get it building again?

Comment: I say "minimum", as these sort of things tend to work themselves out if you reboot everything - wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log into the MAC like a regular human (I use VNC)
2. Restart Visual Studio

You no longer need to start any Xamarin apps on the build host.

The Visual Studio output window, showing output from Xamarin was the key.

[image]

```
An error occured starting the IDB 4.0.1.89 agent: The user 'blahblah' must be logged in on the mac in order to start the agent. Please make sure the user 'blahblah' is logged in and try to connect to the mac again.
```